# Ajax auto fill on dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a invoice form and users can add as many parts as they want. When the user enters the part number, i have an ajax script that auto fills the description and the price.

The script works for the first initial input fields but when i add more input fields, the script doesnt work on the new input fields:

******Please check my updates****** - still not working

```
<table id="partstable" class="table order-list2 table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" >
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th width="30%">Part #</th>
     <th width="30%">Part Desc.</th>
     <th  size="4">Part Price</th>
     <th>Part Qty</th>
     <th>Total</th>
     <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="input-small classpp" name="partnumber" id="partnumber0"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="input-small classd" name="partdescription1" id="partdescription0"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="input-small classp" name="partprice" id="partprice0"  size="4" onblur="doCalcoriginal(); calculate(); "></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partquantity" id="partquantity0"  size="4" onblur="doCalcoriginal(); calculate(); showMessage(); "></td>
     <input type="hidden" readonly class="partdb" size="4" name="partdb" id="partdb0" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px solid;" >
     <td><span class="amount" ></span></td>
     <td><a class="deleteRow2"></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
        <input type="button" id="addrow2" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count 0;
$( "#partstable" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber"+count , function() {


 searchString=$(this).val();


   var data = 'partnumber='+searchString;


   if(searchString) {
       // ajax call

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "partpricequery.php",
           data: data,

          success: function(html){ 

   result = String(html).split("|"),


var counter=0;
loop{
$("#partdescription"+counter).val(result[0]);
$("#partprice"+counter).val(result[1]);
counter++;
 }



showlabel ();

         }
       });    
   }
   return false;
   });

</script>
```

Add more button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 0;

$("#addrow2").on("click", function () {
    doCalc();
    doCalcoriginal();
    calculate();
    grandsum();


    counter = $('#partstable tr').length - 2;

    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td><input text="text" class="input-small" name="partnumber" id="partnumber'+counter+'" /></td>';
    cols += '<td><input text="text" class="input-small" name="partdescription" id="partdescription'+counter+'"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input class="input-small" size="4" type="text" name="partprice" id="partprice'+counter+'" onblur="doCalc(); doCalcoriginal(); calculate(); calculate2();"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input class="input-small" size="4" type="text" name="partquantity" id="partquantity"'+counter+'" onblur="doCalc(); doCalcoriginal(); calculate(); calculate2();"/></td>';
    cols += '<input type="hidden" readonly class="parttotal" size="4" name="partdb[]" style="background-color: transparent;border: 0px solid;" >';
    cols += '<td><span class="amount"></span></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-danger"  value="X"></td>';

    newRow.append(cols);
    if (counter == 100) $('#addrow2').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
    $("table.order-list2").append(newRow);
    counter++;
});

 $("table.order-list2").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    doCalc();
    doCalcoriginal();
    calculate();
    grandsum();


    counter -= 1
    $('#addrow2').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Row");
 });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
$( "#partnumber" ).on( 'blur keyup' , function() {
    .................
});
```

The event is binded to the elements that exist at the time the `.on()` method is called e.g. document load.
You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created elements.

So target a parent say the actual table that holds the inputs and use a delegated event like:

```
$( "table" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber" , function() {
    .................
});
```

This will now listen for events on the table's descendants by looking for events that bubble up to the table rather than directly attaching to these elements.

Comment: it now fires on each #partnumber but it only auto fills the first partdescription and partprice

Comment: Because you're targeting a generic element with `$("#partdescription").val(result[0]),  $("#partprice").val(result[1]),` which is the first one it comes across.  You'll need to determine the index.   Easiest way to is just add an index from your counter variable to their class/id/name when they are created so you can easily distinguish them.

Comment: @JD6969  take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/sdbrannum/pen/aJWqzr?editors=1010) example.  It will give you an idea on how to target specific rows and inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using id. That is the problem. When using "id", the first one only works. Always use class when there are multiple elements.

remove id="partnumber" and use class="partnumber"